# Using SignalR for Sending/Receiving Notifications in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, signalr-2, signalr.net-client

Can I use SignalR in Xamarin.Forms for sending/receiving notifications?
For example, can I send notifications to a server or receive notifications through Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: yes you should be able to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean making the app able to receive notifications even if it's not running, consider using platform `Push Notification` or a wrapper that provide one Api for all platforms, like `OneSignal`

`SignalR` is intended to solve diffident problem, it uses `Websocket` with a possible fallback to `Server Sent Events` or `Long Polling` to implement Real-Time communication with the server, witch is suitable for Chatting App as an example